# K8S api cloud.google.com not available in GKE v1.16.13-gke.401

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a BackendConfig resource on a GKE cluster v1.16.13-gke.401 but it gives me the following error:

```
unable to recognize "backendconfig.yaml": no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1"
```

I have checked the available apis with the `kubectl api-versions` command and cloud.google.com is not available. How can I enable it?

I want to create a BackendConfig whit a custom health check like this:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 8
    timeoutSec: 1
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 3
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /health
    port: 10257
```

And attach this BackendConfig to a Service like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}'
```

Comment: Do you want to create only a `BackendConfig` or you already created a service with annotation `cloud.google.com/backend-config:` ? Could you share your `BackendConfig`?

Comment: @PjoterS I have edited my post to specify what I need to achieve

Comment: Did you tried changing the context to your cluster? 
What does following command returns 'kubectl config current-context'?

Comment: Ive tried your Yamls (adding ports in svc) and everythings work properly on my new cluster. I guess that `cloud.google.com/v1beta1` is also not working. Could you share outputs of `$ kubectl get crd | grep backend`, `$ kubectl api-versions | grep cloud`. Could you verify if Add-on `HTTP Load Balancing` is enable? Did you create new cluster or upgraded it?

Comment: @PjoterS none of the commands you mentioned return output. its a new cluster created with Terraform using the Regular channel. All add-ons are disabled (application manager, HTTP load balancing, config connector and compute engine persistent disk CSI driver).

Comment: If outputs are empty it didn't created proper CRD's. If you would create cluster using default setting it would create CRDs and api-versions. Please enable `HTTP Load Balancing` Add-on (you can do it using UI) or command `gcloud beta container clusters update <clustername> --update-addons=HttpLoadBalancing=ENABLED --zone=<your-zone>` Please let me know if this help, if no, it would be possible to provide terraform config?

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same issue and no clues anywhere :-(
It fails with:
> no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1"

Comment: As Pjoter mentioned, this is likely because the loadbalancer add on is not enabled. Can you share the terraform resource you used? Also, if you try to create a default cluster in GKE using the console and the same version, do you have the same issue?

Comment: I enabled the load balancer add on and the cloud.google.com api was effectively enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, issue was caused due to the lack of `HTTP Load Balancing` add-on in your cluster.

When you are creating GKE cluster with all default setting, feature like `HTTP Load Balancing` is enabled.

> The HTTP Load Balancing add-on is required to use the Google Cloud Load Balancer with Kubernetes Ingress. If enabled, a controller will be installed to coordinate applying load balancing configuration changes to your GCP project

More details can be found in [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer).

For test I have created `Cluster-1` without `HTTP Load Balancing` add-on. There was no `BackendConfig CRD` - [Custom Resource Definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#customresourcedefinitions).

> The CustomResourceDefinition API resource allows you to define custom resources. Defining a CRD object creates a new custom resource with a name and schema that you specify. The Kubernetes API serves and handles the storage of your custom resource. The name of a CRD object must be a valid DNS subdomain name.

Without `BackendConfig` and without `cloud` `apiVersion` like below

```
user@cloudshell:~ (k8s-tests-XXX)$ kubectl get crd | grep backend
user@cloudshell:~ (k8s-tests-XXX)$ kubectl api-versions | grep cloud
```

I was not able to create any `BackendConfig`.

```
user@cloudshell:~ (k8s-tests-XXX) $ kubectl apply -f bck.yaml
error: unable to recognize "bck.yaml": no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1"
```

**To make it work, you have to enable `HTTP Load Balancing`** You can do it via UI or command.

Using UI:

> Navigation Menu > Clusters > [Cluster-Name] > Details > Clikc on
> `Edit` > Scroll down to `Add-ons` and expand > Find `HTTP load balancing` and change from `Disabled` to `Enabled`.

or command:

```
gcloud beta container clusters update <clustername> --update-addons=HttpLoadBalancing=ENABLED --zone=<your-zone>

$ gcloud beta container clusters update cluster-1 --update-addons=HttpLoadBalancing=ENABLED --zone=us-central1-c
WARNING: Warning: basic authentication is deprecated, and will be removed in GKE control plane versions 1.19 and newer. For a list of recommended authentication methods, see: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication
```

After a while, when Add-on was enabled:

```
$ kubectl get crd | grep backend
backendconfigs.cloud.google.com             2020-10-23T13:09:29Z
$ kubectl api-versions | grep cloud
cloud.google.com/v1
cloud.google.com/v1beta1
$ kubectl apply -f bck.yaml 
backendconfig.cloud.google.com/my-backendconfig created
```